# git push and deploy for golang appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

`appcfg.py --oauth2 update ./` works but want to replace it with git push and deploy. After succesfull push, appengine gives me errors that my .go files are not compiled.

Is it possible for appengine to compile the files when using a git repo? If not do I need to place the compiled files in another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [This is a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10005). Please star it.

For now, all you can do is keep using `appcfg.py`. If it is cumbersome to do the OAuth authorisation all the time (or you have multiple accounts), consider storing your refresh token and then doing:

```
appcfg.py update . --oauth2 --oauth2_refresh_token=`cat .token`
```